# Azure APIM policies

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

i am exploring Azure APIM policies.could you please help to find out the solutions for inbound & outbound policy. Basically read the path parameter from url and filter the response based on  path parameter value.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with follow steps:
1.declare a variable and get the parameter with - context.Variables["maxAge"].

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-policy-expressions

2.Using for loop you can filter the response object received from backend.
https://www.codit.eu/blog/using-liquid-templates-in-azure-api-management/

Example below-

```
 {% JSONArrayFor orderline in body.GetOrderDetailsResponse.OrderLines %}
      {
         "product" : "{{orderline.Product}}",
         "amount" : "{{orderline.Amount}}"
      }
   {% endJSONArrayFor %}
```

Comment: Thanks but in mycase i dont have backend service ready so i am mocking sample response.